# @RequestParam in Spring MVC with required=false uses parameter as mandatory

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, kotlin

I'm trying to include a nullable RequestParam but Spring seems to be taking it as mandatory

Controller:

```
open fun calculate(@RequestHeader(name = USER_ID_HEADER, required = true) userId: String,
                   @RequestParam(name = "product_price_amount", required = true) productPriceAmount: BigDecimal,
                   @RequestParam(name = "product_price_currency", required = true) productPriceCurrency: String,
                   @RequestParam(name = "item_id", required = true) itemId: String,
                   @RequestParam(name = "promocode", required = true) promocode: String,
                   @RequestParam(value = "carrier_delivery_mode",
                                 required = false, defaultValue = "BUYER_ADDRESS") carrierDeliveryMode: String? = "BUYER_ADDRESS"
```

GET request

```
calculator/costs?product_price_amount=100&product_price_currency=EUR&item_id=g9kp615z5l32&promocode=1LL
```

I get the following error:

> [
>       {
>           "error_code": "Bad Request",
>           "message": "Parameter conditions \"product_price_amount, product_price_currency, item_id, promocode, carrier_delivery_mode\" not met for actual request parameters: product_price_amount={100}, product_price_currency={EUR}, item_id={g9kp615z5l32}, promocode={1LL}"
>       }
>   ]

Any ideas why this is failing?

Comment: Not sure but you can try 100.00 for big decimal

Comment: Did you try `carrierDeliveryMode: String` instead of `carrierDeliveryMode: String?`?

Comment: I did, and it does not work

Answer (score 1):

You already have a default value in the annotation. Please remove this ? = "BUYER_ADDRESS" part and just keep it carrierDeliveryMode: String. Hope was helpful :)

Comment: strange! In java, we use Optional as an alternative of the 'required' param but Since optionality is Kotlin is inbuilt into the type system, there are no dedicated static factory methods or any other special mechanisms for wrapping our classes, I have no solution in mind :(

Comment: It was the params in the GetMapping. I removed them and worked!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the params in the @GetMapping and it worked :)

```
@GetMapping("calculator/costs",
                params = ["product_price_amount", "product_price_currency", "item_id", "promocode", "carrier_delivery_mode"])
```

Comment: Oh that part was hidden :)) happy for you